# Buying extra storage from Google for more than one year

Tags: gmail, google-drive, online-storage

Is it possible to buy Gmail extra storage for more than one year at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not possible, but it will be renewed automatically if you won't cancel it. They are sending an e-mail when it is close to the end.

Don't forget that the storage prices are usually getting cheeper over time and you don't really want to prepay that.